# The SQL command is not properly ended error

Tags: sql, oracle, dml

I'm getting the error the 'The SQL command is not properly ended.' when trying to run this query. Can someone please help me to recognize what the issue of this is.

```
UPDATE PM_ACTION_CALENDAR_PLAN_TAB 
   SET t1.GEN_DATE = t2.GEN_DATE 
  FROM PM_ACTION_CALENDAR_PLAN_TAB t1 
       INNER JOIN  GEN_DATEPREPARE2 t2 
         ON t1.PM_NO = t2.PM_NO AND 
            t1.SEQ_NO=t2.SEQ_NO AND 
            t1.PM_REVISION=t2.PM_REVISION;
```

Comment: Oracle doesn't support `update .. from .. join` sysntax. User [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) instead.

Comment: Hi How can I do this in oracle?

Comment: UPDATE t1 
   SET t1.GEN_DATE = t2.GEN_DATE 
  FROM PM_ACTION_CALENDAR_PLAN_TAB t1 
       INNER JOIN  GEN_DATEPREPARE2 t2 
         ON t1.PM_NO = t2.PM_NO AND 
            t1.SEQ_NO=t2.SEQ_NO AND 
            t1.PM_REVISION=t2.PM_REVISION;

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  UPDATE PM_ACTION_CALENDAR_PLAN_TAB  t1
       SET t1.GEN_DATE = (select t2.GEN_DATE 
                            from GEN_DATEPREPARE2 t2 
                           where t2.PM_NO = t1.PM_NO 
                             AND t2.SEQ_NO = t1.SEQ_NO 
                             AND t2.PM_REVISION = t1.PM_REVISION)
```